# authorization for media library dose not run the handler

Tags: ios, swift, mpmedialibrary

```
    MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
       if status == MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus.authorized  {
          print("Accepted")
       } else {
          print("not authorized")
       }
    }
```

The code above worked fine until 12.3.1 update of iOS. But now the closure is not calling at all. Have anybody encountered this yet or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
    MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        if status == .authorized {
            print("Accepted")
        } else {
            print("not authorized")
        }
    }
```

Comment: and in info.plist add      <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
 <string>This app uses your media library in order to track changes</string>

Comment: I already added. it asks for authorization but whatever you choose, the closure doesn't run.

Comment: if you want to send the screenshot

Comment: it is the iOS 12.3.1, because  my old apps also show the same symptoms. They did something!